# Can "addMaterialCommandToSideMenu" set different styles for different items?

Tags: codenameone

for example, I want to have different colors for each item in side menu:

```
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Home",FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME,e->{});
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Website",FontImage.MATERIAL_WEB,e->{});
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Settings",FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS,e->{});
```

is it possible to set individual theme for each item (e.g.:"Home" use "Theme1","Website" use "Theme2")?

I cannot find any MaterialCommand type which allows me to set theme individually, is "addMaterialCommandToSideMenu" not suitable to have different items with different themes? if so, how can I achieve this? (eg:add each Button individually to the Toolbar? How?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorthand here doesn't include that feature at this time. You can probably create your own material icon with any style then use `addCommandToSideMenu` instead.

You can customize the uiid of the command by placing a client property as such:

```
myCmd.putClientProperty("uiid", "MyUIID");
```

This probably won't work after you added the command as by then the UI was already created.

Another approach is using `findCommandComponent(cmd)` which returns a button you can customize.